# z-index in mobile not working

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Is there a specific way of formatting z-index for mobile? Does it even work?

www.backwards.ca/resume

This is what I'm working on.. In mobile, the body (.info-win) is supposed to scroll up UNDER the header(.name-win), but it's not working

This is the code:

```
body{
background:#EEE;
margin-top:0;
margin-left:0;
}

.container{
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding-left:0;
background:#EEE;
}

.name-win{
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
height:25%;
width:100%;
z-index:10000px;
padding-left:5%;
background:#EEE;
-moz-box-shadow:-2px 0px 2px 3px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
-webkit-box-shadow:-2px 0px 2px 3px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
-o-box-shadow:-2px 0px 2px 3px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
box-shadow:-2px 0px 2px 3px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
}

.scroll{
background:none;
}

.info-win{
position:relative;
margin-top:25%;
background:#FFFFFF;
height:100%;
width:100%;
z-index:-1000px;
min-height:500px;
overflow:hidden;
padding-bottom:20px;
}

.name-win h1{
font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
font-weight:700;
max-width:200px;
}

#pic{
float:left;
}

#pic img{
width:60%;
border:6px solid #fff;
}

.res_cont{
width:100%;
}

.contact h3{
margin-bottom:0px;
font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
font-weight:700;
}

.contact p{
margin-top:0px;
font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
font-weight:300;
}

.label{
height:33px;
width:420px;
padding-left:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

.label h2{
font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
color:#fff;
text-shadow:1px 1px #555;
}

.res_cont p{
font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
color:#555;
margin-left:25px;
}

.res_cont span{
font-style:italic;
color:#999;
}

#objective_label{
background-color:#4F8AFF;
}

#rs_label{
background-color:#CC0000;
}

#about_label{
background-color:#00CC66;
}

#education_label{
background-color:#FF6633;
}

#links_label{
background:#E4B434
}

#links_ul li{
font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
color:#666;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it on a desktop browser to ensure that this is indeed related to mobile browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

z-index is supposed to be a numerical value like in `z-index: 2;` You're using the unit **px** with them. Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

z-index values having a 'px' appended to the end will not work. Just change these values to integers. Try removing the px and see if that helps.

```
z-index: 1
```

instead of

```
z-index: 1px
```

Comment: "tend to have issues"? Sorry, but using pixel-values on `z-index` is just nonsense. Allowed value types are `auto | <integer> | inherit`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/z-index

Comment: @feeela - Poor choice of words. Answer modified. Thx.